# How to split three single columns into one big column?

Tags: c#, excel

I've got this type of data in my Datatable. Imagine that ("2019_WK1", "2019_WK2", "2019_WK3") is the three column names and so i need to take split 2019(year) in one big merged cell, (Upper "WK1", "WK2", "WK3") column cells in C#.

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Below are my datatable code:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Excel.Range chartRange;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            //add data 
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Retailer";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Brand";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "2019_WK1";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "2019_WK2";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "2019_WK3";


            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Lulu";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "Perisil";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3] = "25";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 4] = "26";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 5] = "23";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Lulu";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "Ariel";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 3] = "26";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 4] = "28";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 5] = "29";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 1] = "Danube";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 2] = "Omo";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 3] = "27";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 4] = "28";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 5] = "30";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 1] = "Danube";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 2] = "Tide";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 3] = "24";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 4] = "23";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 5] = "29";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 1] = "Bin Dawood";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 2] = "Perisil";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 3] = "26";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 4] = "27";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 5] = "28";

xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\csharp.net-informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlApp);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);

            MessageBox.Show("File created !");
        }
```

I need like this type of columns

```
  ____________________________
  |            2019           |
  |___________________________|
  |  WK1   l   WK2  l   WK3   |
  |________l________l_________|
  |  25    |   26   |   23    |
  |  27    |   29   |   24    |
  ___24________25_______22_____
```

Comment: It's a little hard to understand with the text - can you mock up an example of the input, and expected output, as you'd see it in Excel?

Comment: Try to create a `Range` of cells (Cells in row 1, columns 3, 4, 5) and then call `Range.Merge();`

Comment: Can you explain how to create range of cells and how to call?...i am trying a lot but not getting success